# How to include a conditional in Promise.prototype.then()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using axios to fetch an API and need to include a conditional based on the data returned:

```
axios.get('https://api.url.endpoint).then(response => ())
```

How would I go about making a conditional statement based on the response (specifically to check if a property of the response returns null)?

Thanks for your help.

Using an if..else statement with the response such as below does not work.

```
axios.get('https://api.url.endpoint).then(response => (
if (response.data != null) { }
))
```

Comment: what is the response do you get ?

Comment: you can do it as you will do normally outside Promise.then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the notion is to still throw an error if the result *is not* `null` then

```
axios.get('...')
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.data) throw new Error('No data');

    return res.data
  });
```

Although, I think this would be easier with `async` / `await`

```
const res = await axios.get('...');
if (res.data) {
  // happy day scenario
} else {
  // bad day scenario
}
```